# How to open specific page from notification?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mfp-push
I need open current page on app when onclick on notification

Answer (score 0):

Within your callback to handle push :

```
MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);
```

you can define logic to display the page you need.